# How to obtain 2 matrices from a text document with words in java?

Tags: java, matrix, file-io, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to make this program where I create a matrix and do a matrix multiplication. 
I need to retrieve the matrices from a document that looks like this(yes, each section is separated):

```
matrix
row
1
2
-2
0
row
-3
4
7
2
row
6
0
3
1
matrix
row
-1
3
row
1
-11
row
4
-5
```

The start of a new matrix will be indicated with "matrix". The start of a new row will be indicated with "row" followed by the numbers assigned to each column of that row.
The finished 2 matrices should look like this:

```
{ {1,2,-2,0}, {-3,4,7,2}, {6,0,3,1} };
{ {-1, 3}, {0,9},{1,-11},{4,-5}};
```

Since I need to separate each row and column from a file, how should I create the 2 matrices? I have 0 idea on how to make the matrices from the text because I don't know how to separate it from the text. 
This is what I am doing after the matrix is created.

```
public class Tester{
   public static void main(String args[]){

    int a[][] = new int[][]{ {1,2,-2,0}, {-3,4,7,2}, {6,0,3,1} };
    int b[][] = new int[][]{ {-1, 3}, {0,9},{1,-11},{4,-5}};


    int c[][] = MatrixMult.mult(a,b);

    for (int[] row : c) {
            for (int x : row) {
                    System.out.print(x + " "); 
        }
    System.out.println("");
    }

   }
```

The mult function requires 2 arrays and return a product of matrix multiplication:

```
public class MatrixMult{
   public static int[][] mult(int arrayA[][], int arrayB[][]){

    int rowA = arrayA.length;
    int colA = arrayA[0].length;
    int rowB = arrayB.length;
    int colB = arrayB[0].length;


        int[][] product = new int[rowA][colB];
        for(int x = 0; x < rowA; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < colB; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < colA; z++) {
                    product[x][y] += arrayA[x][z] * arrayB[z][y];
                }
            }
        }
    return product;
   }
}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
public class Tester{
   public static void main(String args[]){



    Scanner fileInput  = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\b8897\\Desktop\\DataGym.in"));

    int maxIndex = -1;
    String[] line = new String[1000];


    int a[][] = new int[][];
    int b[][] = new int[][];

    while (fileInput.hasNext()){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner()

    }

    fileInput.close();

    for (int x = 0; x<=maxIndex;x++){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(line[x]);


        while(sc.hasNext()){
        if(sc.next().equals("matrix"){


            total+= Double.parseDouble(sc.next());

        }



    }
```

Can I have some advice logic wise on how to separate the words and rows?